# can i set a Activiti user task to multiple candidate groups?

Tags: java, activiti

Normally I set the Activiti user task to a assignee,  candidate users or a candidate group. I'm wondering if I can set multiple candidate groups not just a candidate group like :

```
group1, group2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DelegateTask to add multiple groups as candidate group, with method: [addCandidateGroups](https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/delegate/DelegateTask.html#addCandidateGroups-java.util.Collection-)

example:

```java
    @Component("CustomTaskListener")
    public class CustomTaskListener implements TaskListener {
    
        @Override
        public void notify(DelegateTask task) {
            
            List<String> groups = new ArrayList<>();
            groups.add("group1");
            groups.add("group2");
            
            task.addCandidateGroups(groups);
        }
    }
```